# How to convert raster dtype from uint8 to float32?

Tags: python, numpy

I want to make stack of multiple rasters but some of them have float32 and some of them have uint8 as dtype. which giving me this **error** :

***ValueError: the array's dtype 'uint8' does not match the file's dtype 'float32'***

My used code:

```
import os
import earthpy.spatial as es
from earthpy.io import path_to_example
band_fnames = ["red.tif", "green.tif", "blue.tif"]
band_paths = [path_to_example(fname) for fname in band_fnames]
destfile = "./stack_result.tif"
arr, arr_meta = es.stack(band_paths, destfile)
```

Anybody has idea how to solve this?

Comment: Can you find the error output and copy it as text in code blocks here? Images are in many ways inferior in representing text-based information (cannot be indexed & searched, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `astype` method of numpy arrays:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1, 2], dtype=np.unit8)
a.dtype
>>> dtype('uint8')

b = a.astype(np.float32)
b.dtype
>>> dtype('float32')

# values are the same but now floats
b
>>> array([1., 2.], dtype=float32)
```

I would suggest converting all the arrays you want to stack to be the same `dtype` using something like this above.